# Do you ever NOT want to use virtual inheritance of a mutual base class if you use multiple is-a inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

If you have is-a inheritance relationships implemented with public inheritance, and have a diamond of inheritance you will have something like:

- a stream class
- input stream and output stream classes derived from stream
- an input/output stream class derived from both

In this case, as used in the standard library (?), to the extent that iostream both is-a istream and is-a ostream, the istream isa-a stream and the ostream is-a stream, and furthermore they are the *same* stream, any functions in stream, which it makes sense to apply to iostream, should deal with the same underlying structure.

In C++, in order that the copies of stream in istream and ostream can be shared, it must be inherited by them virtually.

However, if you prefer, you can *not* inherit virtually and each time you refer to a member of the base class, specify which of the two copies (one in istream or one in ostream) you want (either by casting, or by using scope::blah).

My question is, [edit: is there any other case where] other than "This isn't really an is-a relationship, I used naughtily used public inheritance as a syntactic convenience when it wasn't conceptually valid" or "I never need to refer polymorphically to the base class from the most-derived class so the incredibly small overhead isn't worth it", there is any reason it WOULD be conceptually valid to inherit non-virtually and have two copies of the base class, one for each sister intermediate class?

Comment: I wish all question on SO were asked so well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's work into a simple example.

```
   B           B1   B2
   |             \ /
   D              D
```

On the left, we find a class derived from a single bass.  Clearly reasonable in OO design for having an is-a relationship respecting the Liskov Substitution Principal.

On the right, both `B1` and `B2` are independent bases of `D`, and `D` can be accessed polymorphically using a `B1*` or `B2*` (or references).  Hopefully we can accept that this is also a valid OO design (despite Sun deeming it too stressfully mind-bending for Java programmers ;-P).  Then consider having some base functionality factored out of both `B1` and `B2` and made reusable: say they both operate on an arbitrary list of numbers to which they can reasonably grant direct/`public` access:

```
   Container<int>   Container<int>
              \     /
              B1   B2
                \ /
                 D
```

If this isn't clicking yet, perhaps:

```
   Container<int>   Container<int>
              \     /
            Ages  Heights
                \ /
             Population
```

It is reasonable to say that `Ages` is-a `Container<int>`, though it might add some convenient functionality like `average`, `min`, `max`, `num_teenagers`.  Same for `Heights`, possibly sporting a different set of convenience functions.  Clearly a `Population` can reasonably be substituted for an `Ages` or `Heights` collection (e.g. `size_t num_adults(Ages&); if (num_adults(my_population)) ...`).

The point here is that each supporting container isn't meant to have a 1:1 relationship with further-derived classes like `Population`; rather, it's meant to be **exactly 1:1 with its immediately-derived class**.

Again, whether composition or inheritance is used is an interface design decision, but it's not necessarily invalid to expose the containers publicly in this way.  (If there's concern about maintaining `Population` invariants such as `Ages::empty() == Heights::empty()` the data-mutating functions of `Container<int>` might be made `protected` while `const` member functions were `public`.)

As you observe, `Population` does not have an unambiguous is-a relationship with `Container<int>` and code may need explicit disambiguation.  That's appropriate.  Of course, it's also possible and reasonable for `Population` to derive from `Container<int>` if it stores some other set of numbers, but that would be independent of the indirectly inherited containers.

> My question is, other than "This isn't really an is-a relationship, I used naughtily used public inheritance as a syntactic convenience when it wasn't conceptually valid"

I see no issue with the is-a relationships or conceptual validity of the above, if you do please explain....

> "I never need to refer polymorphically to the base class from the most-derived class so the incredibly small overhead isn't worth it"

I think it's clear I'm just doing data modelling based on natural object relationships, not some dubious optimisation.  The supporting container class factored out of the bases is actually used and must be independent in each.

Comment: A possibility of default casting is the main difference between inheritance and other (conceptually simpler) ways to add some functionality to a class. If we loose this possibility, then the use of inheritance becomes a questionable decision. I'm not going to go as far as Sun :) and I don't reject multiple iheritance itself, but I would treat it as appropriate until it becomes ambiguous.

Comment: @user39676672: given independently both single and multiple inheritance may be reasonable design decisions, then inevitably by combining these you can get ambiguous inheritance situations.  It can even happen during evolution: B1 may already have a `Container<int>` base, then the unrelated class B2 adds one too.  Unknown to the authors of both, D - derived from both B1 and B2, find uses of the `Container<int>` suddenly ambiguous both in D's code and in client code.  Nasty!  But, it doesn't mean the independent inheritance decisions that led to that situation were wrong or should be rethought.

Comment: "a population can reasonably be substituted for a Ages or Heights collection." Interesting example! Took me a while to get it, but I see what you mean. I also like "I'm just doing data modelling based on natural object relationships, not some dubious optimisation". Too many discussions on inheritance seem dominated by people insisting composition must do everything and `virtual`s are a performance devil. I'm becoming a better judge of why composition _is_ better in many cases, but I don't rule out inheritance. My maxim is 'If you need it, you'll know you need it, because it'll be a lifesaver'!

Comment: @underscore_d: that *"...reasonably be substituted..."* bit was a little more cryptic than it should have been - I've added an example - but glad you understood it anyway.  Completely agree with you about the importance of keeping an open mind about when to use inheritance vs. composition, and consider actual hands-on pros/cons in real code.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is more likely to cause havoc.

Let us ignore the case of stateful base class. It seems obvious that having two incoherent states is likely to cause confusion at least, and be error prone.

I would rather focus on the issue of identity. In C++, the identity of an object is determined by its address. This is the very reason why, apart from empty base classes, each object must at least have a size of one byte.

If you have the same base class multiple times in your hierarchy, then you could obtain two `Base*` that refer to the same object... and yet differ (point to a difference address).

Of course, you could pull your tricks and use a `dynamic_cast<void*>(p)` to get the "real" physical address of the whole object... but still.

Comment: I agree that's an excellent explanation of the problems, but lots of things are prone to horrednous mistakes -- multiple inheritance itself is deprecated in several successors to C++, but I think it still has applications sometimes, and I don't _think_ non-virtual multiple inheritance from the same object has any applications, but I'm still not _positive_

Comment: @Jack V: Neither am I, your question is somewhat akin to "does *this* exist", proving that something exists is easy, proving that it does not require a formal framework, which we lack here.

Comment: yeah, I'd agree with that. I was hoping that either (a) there _was_ an example (b) there was a commonly understood best practice (with citation) that there wasn't or (c) that it was logically incoherent with the is-a principle. But if there isn't, I guess I'll mark one of the "I don't know, but I can't think of one" answers correct :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is one of identity; in the case of the iostream
hierarchy, the shared bases even have state, which gets set by
manipulators.  If there were more than one instance of
basic_ios, you'ld have two copies of the state (formatting
flags, error state, even the streambuf), which would be
a disaster.

I can't really think of a case where you'ld want two copies of
a base class, but I imagine that they do exist.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer. All you have done is to restate the observation of the OP and say that you too cannot think of an appropriate example.

Comment: I thought I explained why his suggestion of not using virtual inheritance in the iostream hierarchy couldn't work.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I expected everyone would agree that the example given was one of the overwhelming majority which DOES need virtual inheritance. I was thinking is there "any case EVER where non-v makes sense", not "does it make sense for this case", but I see my last paragraph was perhaps ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

An example

```
class Category
{   
public:
    virtual std::string CatName(); 
};

class OxygenBreath : public Category
{
public:
    virtual void Breath() = 0;
    std::string CatName(){ return "OxygenBreath";}
};

class LandWalk : public Category  
{
public:
    virtual void Walk() = 0;
    std::string CatName(){ return "LandWalk";}
};

class Human : public OxygenBreath, public LandWalk
{};
```

Comment: @Shuo: This is a confusing example. Is `Human` a `Category`, or does it belong to the two categories `LandWalk` and `OxygenBreath`?

Comment: I like where you're going with this, but isn't Category pure abstract, ie contains no data ie acts as an interface ie there aren't ANY copies of it in the most derived class at all, whether it's virtual or not? I almost mentioned inheriting interfaces in the question but at the time I thought it would only muddle matters.

Comment: (Which copy of the base class would matter if there were a base class function which called a base class function declared virtual, which was overrridden differently in the sister intermediate classes, but this doesnt' appear to be the case. Also, I don't think this example is clear on what the conceptual concept it's trying to convey IS? Wouldn't it be better for the category text to be static, and a template used to make a _different_ category class for each category, depending how it's intended to be used?)

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y The Human is not a category, but it belongs to the two categories LandWalk and OxygenBreath, so it only cares about the LandWalk::Walk() and OxygenBreath::Breath(). Human itself don't care about the category interface.

Comment: @Shuo: In this case you shouldn't use inheritance, but composition, because `Human` *has-a* category.

Comment: @Jack V.: Whether the Category has data member, it doesn't care too much here. Just in concept there are 2 or 1 Category in the perspective of Human. If it is not virtual, then in Human, there are 2 CatName(), if it is, there is only one CatName, right?

Answer (score 0):

There might be cases where this is useful. Say a `touchscreen` class deriving from `display_device` and `input_device`? Now suppose <strike>each base</strike> the common base class has an `estimated_power_consumption` field, wouldn't it be useful to avoid virtual inheritance?

Comment: I'm not convinced. This sounds again like it `input_device` and `display_device` should be abstract, and only the concrete `touchscreen` should have a power consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically speaking, I can imagine a reason to inherit "sisters" B and C from common A non-virtually *privately* , then inherit publicaly some "compound class" D  from A and B.

It is, of course, not an is_a relationshipn between most derived (D) and most base class (A) as private inheritance does not exhibit is_a relationship to users and furher descendants.

However, if B and C sister classes are not designed especially for this case (i.e for diamond inheritance),  they may be publicaly inherited from A.

The effect is almost the same as for private inheritance: we can't access A members from D (**[edited**:at least without explicit casting to sisters; **]** any attempt will be ambiguous).
So one may treat public nonvirtual inheritance as a replacement for private nonvirtual inheritance.

But I would never do such tricks. 
Iheritance itself is a useful metaphor but not a basement of the universe, and using it subtle features leads to unnecessary complicated design.

IMO, if a replacement of simple(nonvirtual) inheritance with virtual one is (conceptually) unacceptable, there is almost surely a design flaw.

So I would answer "no" (despite of my "theretically speaking..." construction :)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct managed
{
    report(std::string what);

private:
    manager_type manager;

protected:
    managed(manager_type);
};

struct human : managed
{
    human() : managed(god) {}
};

struct robot : managed
{
    robot(manager_type owner) : managed(owner) {}
};

struct employee : managed
{
    employee(manager_type boss) : managed(boss) {}
};

struct human_employee : human, employee
{
    human_employee(manager_type boss) : employee(boss) {}
};

struct robot_employee : robot, employee
{
    robot_employee(manager_type owner) : robot(owner), employee(owner) {}
};
```

Now, consider:

```
void do_some_duty(const employee& e)
{
    e.do_some_tasks();
    e.report("done");
}

void face_disaster(const human& h)
{
    h.report("Oh my!");
}

void commit_suicide(const managed& m)
{
    m.report("I want to suicide");
}
```

and as a human employee, the one you report to is different if you're working of not:

```
human_employee h;
if (h.at_work()) commit_suicide(static_cast<const employee&>(h));
else commit_suicide(static_cast<const human&>(h));
```

I would even consider using such a design if I really needed to. You can imagine in lieu of `managed` some class which would store a reference to a global manager object for eg. garbage collection. In this case it really makes sense to have distinct base classes for base objects.

Comment: To access "managed" from human_employee you need static_cast<> i.e. some special casting expession. The same goal may be achieved without inheritance, for instance, making employee and human public members(not parents) of human_employee class.
In this case static_cast will be replaced with something like  h.as_human or h.as_employer (or one may provide a casting function like query_interface()).
IMO inheritance need to be used if there is possible _default_ casting to the parent. Otherwise it is a trick and the same goal may be (more clearly) achieved without inheritance at all.

Comment: @user396672: what you say is true of all inheritance mechanisms: you can have a member and a `as_base()` method whenever you use inheritance. This is even how it is implemented! The langage allows you to bypass such mechanism if there is no ambiguity in base classes. With multiple inheritance, there will be ambiguities. The point here is that a `human_employee` **is a** `employee` **and** a `human`, and both **are** `managed`. If there is a "default parent" as you say, then you should use virtual inheritance. If there is not, you **have** to resolve the ambiguity whenever it makes sense.

Comment: @Alexander:I'd say human_employee is NOT simply employee and a human since both are also managed but I can't substute managed with human_employee(according to Liskov Principle). So it's _not_ an is_a relationship between human_employee and it parents. is_managed and is_managed_as_human  are different predicates!
A practical reason to use inheritance instead of as_base() is _uniformity_ of usage (for instance, in templates). If the uniformity dissapears... 
I agree, however, that we need to distingish OO design and language mechanisms which may be occasionally convinient for diffrent tasks.

Comment: Interesting discussion. I see the ambiguity around having 2 managers, vs the temptation to say 'but that last example sorta does make sense...' But I really came here to say LOL at the choices of names and methods.